# yet another INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when using Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I went through all the articles about the INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY issue in Google Maps projects but I couldn't find a case similar to mine nor a solution, so here is my problem:

I have a project with an activity (com.example.googleMaps.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity) that inherits from MapView to show a Google Map and do some stuff.
I run it on a Samsung Galaxy S II and it works fine: it shows the map and does the stuff it is supposed to do.

Now. 
I want to use this project as a library for another project and show that activity as the first screen of another app.

So I checked the box Is Library, I created a new android project that builds against GoogleAPI and includes the library in the Android properties in Eclipse with the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.example.googleMaps" required="true" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" required="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.example.googleMaps.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I run this new project on my device and I get the infamous error:
INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
and LogCat is totally silent.

I would like to point out that the activity inside the library works so none of the well know issues should apply.

In the client project I specify two *uses-library* tags (one for my library and one for the Google library), I build against GoogleAPI, include the library in the Android properties in Eclipse and run on a tested device.

Am I still missing something?

Comment: which SDK have you build against? Android API or Google API?

Comment: @Tomislav Novoselec: GoogleAPI for both projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Use com.google.android.maps. Please remove another one.

Comment: thank you Hardik Trivedi, I figured out that I don't need the uses-library tag for library projects and then read your post but now I get a NoClassDefNotError for the R file of the library project ( java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.googleMaps.R$id) :( do you know what it could be?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, just remove the line:

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.example.googleMaps" required="true" />
```

and it should work.